# Define a structure in C to wrap a float between two numbers

Tags: c, struct

I want to create a structure so that the float would always wrap between two values. (These would be static inside the structure)

For example, if I want an angle structure that wraps between 0 and 360.

```
//Theta would actually have the value of 120.0f
Angle theta = 480.0f;

//Phi would actually have the value of 300.0f
Angle phi = -60.0f;

//Alpha would have the value of 60.0f
Angle alpha = theta + phi;
```

This would continue for all the other mathematical functions.

How would I be able to implement a automatic wrapping inside a struct (or class) in C?

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Consider using C++.

Comment: You can't. You will need to handle it. You can write functions like "add_angle()" which will have this handling inside.

Comment: Another way may be building a (extended) C compiler that supports such types.

Comment: Doesn't look like a reason sufficient to make one switch a language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in C. The best you can do is to write a function like `wrap_angle`, and `typedef float Angle;`, and then write:

```
//Theta would actually have the value of 120.0f
Angle theta = wrap_angle(480.0f);

//Phi would actually have the value of 300.0f
Angle phi = wrap_angle(-60.0f);

//Alpha would have the value of 60.0f
Angle alpha = wrap_angle(theta + phi);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use modulo  if the values are integer.

```
//Theta would actually have the value of 120
Angle theta = 480%360
//Phi would actually have the value of 300
Angle phi = -60%360
//Alpha would have the value of 60
Angle alpha = theta + phi;
```

Comment: Surely won't work for floating point numbers. Also will give range `-359..359`, so `Phi` will be `-60` and not `300`.

Comment: Try using 'fmod()'